# BrowserHistory not working for react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently my URL structure is still storing history in hash syntax. 
Ex: `http://localhost:3000/#/work?_k=otstr8`

Im trying to have it use `browserHistory` from react-router to be displayed as:
`http://localhost:3000/#/work`

Here is my **routes.js** file:

```
//Import Dependencies.
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//Import Components.
import AboutElement from '../views/about/about.jsx';
import WorkElement from '../views/work/work.jsx';
import ResumeElement from '../views/resume/resume.jsx';

//Set up routes.
let routes = (
    <Router>
        <Route path='/' component={AboutElement}/>
        <Route path='/work' component={WorkElement}/>
        <Route path='/resume' component={ResumeElement}/>
    </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

My **index.js** file:

```
//Import Dependencies.
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

//Import Routes.
import routes from './routes/routes.js';

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('application'))
```

From what I have researched this syntax is correct for `browserHistory`? For some reason hash history is still being used. Any ideas why this is still happening?

Comment: browserHistory requires server-side changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created my own variable for browserHistory.

```
//Import Dependencies.
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

//Import Routes.
import routes from './routes/routes.js';

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('application'));
```

The syntax for the url is now: 
localhost:3000/
localhost:3000/**work**
localhost:3000/**resume**

Which is great!

Answer (score 1):

Just install history as a seperate library and use this.

```
import { createHistory } from 'history'

const history = createHistory()
```